# Communication between 2 instances of the same ng component

Tags: jquery, angular, angular10

In a Razor view I have an angular component:

```
<my-widget id="myWidget" isfullscreen="false" class="some-class"></my-widget>
```

When the user clicks on a button 'Popup', a popup is opened in an iframe and I call the same component but with a different attribute value:

```
<my-widget id="myWidget" isfullscreen="true" class="some-class"></my-widget>
```

That means I have 2 different instances of the same component. Now, in that component I have some inputs, dropdowns etc. and in the popup I want them in the same state as they were before the popup is opened. That means if the user changes a value in the dropdown, and he clicks on the 'Popup' button, I don't want the default value of the dropdown to be selected. Instead I want the one he chose before he clicked on the button.

I managed to do this with global variables. On the change event of the dropdown, I set a global variable to the correct value. On the init event of the component, I check if the global variable exists and if it does I use it. I don't like this approach. Is there another way?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your structure, the two Components are not parent and child, they are totally unrelated, right? (even though it's the same component code)

Comment: Yes that's correct, they are unrelated. @Technoh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For communication between two unrelated components, the only way to send data is through the use of services. We often think of services being used to fetch remote data but they are also used to share data between the components of the application. You will need to familiarize yourself with services as well as observables and subjects / behaviorsubjects if it's not already the case. Here is one way to use a service in such a way, from [fireship.io](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#unrelated-components-sharing-data-with-a-service).

data-sharing.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {

  private currentData$ = new BehaviorSubject(0); // change the value to the default value for the dropdown

  constructor() { }

  updateData(data: number) { // change this as well depending on data
    this.currentData$.next(data);
    return this.currentData$;
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSharingService } from "../data-sharing.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: 'app-component,
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.css']
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {    
  dropDownValue: number; // change this depending on your dropdown value

  constructor(private dataSharingService: DataSharingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSharingService.currentData$.subscribe(newData => this.dropDownValue = newData)
  }

  updateValue(event) {
    this.dataSharingService.updateData(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<select id="[...]" name="[...]" [(ngModel)]="[...]" (change)="updateValue($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let [...]" [ngValue]="[...]">[...]</option>
</select>
```

I used a lot of [...] because I don't know how you render your components and I don't even know if you use forms or reactive forms.